# Is it possible to loop in an array and access next loop cycle's elements within current each() loop?

Tags: jquery

lets say i am using a each loop to iterate thru an array and i need to know when i get same values repeatedly.

```
var array = [];
array[33] = 12;
array[3] = 32;
array[323] = 234;
array[25267] = 34;
array[7] = 342;
var valueBuffer;
$.each(array, function( index, value ) {
    if(valueBuffer == value){
        console.log(value+" is the same as previous value");
    }else{
        console.log(value);
    }
    valueBuffer=value;
});
```

here i can do this with buffering the previous value. but i need a way to do that in the current loop. my indexes are not in an order so i cant use a for loop and access +1 index.

what i mean is something like

```
$.each(array, function( index, value ) {
    if(nextLoopValue == value){
        console.log(value+" is the same as next value");
    }else{
        console.log(value);
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "my indexes are not in an order"?

Comment: If they aren't in order how does comparing against next differ from comparing against previous?

Comment: @jamesdonnelley i am using the id from a external dataset as index number of this array.

Comment: @DoctorMick the index numbers are like customer ids each id (index) comes normally once but some customers come twice repeatedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.each(array, function( index, value ) {
    if(array[index+1] == array[index]){
        alert(value+" is the same as next value");
    }else{
        alert(value);
    }
});
```

Comment: jQuery.inArray() use this one or write each loop nested in existing and match if the next index is defined loop until you find next index

Answer (score 0):

```
    var arr = [15,9, 9, 111, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7];
    var sorted_arr = arr.sort();  

    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) {
      if (sorted_arr[i + 1] != sorted_arr[i]) {
       results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
      }
    }

    console.log(results);
```

Comment: if you need duplicated customers ids, change 5th line to if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i])

Comment: i cant use a for loop in my example